# Sudo can't see symbollically linked executables in path

Tags: linux, environment-variables, path, sudo, selinux

On CentOS 7, I installed some executables in `/opt/app-version/bin/executable`. Those executables have the following permissions:

`rwxrwxr-x. 500 500`

Ownership of every directory in the path `/opt/app-version/bin/` is `500 500`--except `/opt`, which is `root root`.

My first question: what is this `500 500` business? Given that I installed the executables using `sudo`, shouldn't the owner and group be `root`?

I've run the following command as root to create symbolic links to the executables in `/usr/local/bin/`:

`ln /opt/app-version/bin/executable /usr/local/bin/executable --symbolic`

I am able to run `executable` from the command line as a regular user, but not as a regular user using `sudo`.

Running `sudo executable` returns `sh: executable: command not found`.

Running `sudo echo $PATH` shows that `/usr/local/bin/` is in `$PATH` for sudo environments. ( Or does it? Am I seeing the contents of `$PATH` for the super user environment, or `$PATH` for the environment of the user that called `sudo`? Does CentOS create a new environment for commands run with `sudo`, or does it just run the command in the caller's environment? )

Running `sudo ls -la /usr/local/bin/executable` returns a listing for `executable` in `/usr/local/bin/` with ownership `lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root`. ( Does `ln --symbolic` really create globally editable links by default? Isn't that--a horrible idea? ) My understanding is that this shows `sudo` *should* be able to run `executable`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking first at the `500 500`, if you restore from a `tar` archive (among others) the owner and group will be preserved from the system where the archive was created: I'm guessing that the installer does this, and if the restored user or group does not exist on your system the numeric value is displayed.

Looking now at the `PATH`, I have reproduced this on Ubuntu, and it seems that `sudo` modifies `PATH`: in your command `sudo echo $PATH` the `PATH` variable was expanded in the original shell before calling `sudo`. There is a file `/etc/sudoers` with an entry `"defaults secure_path="..."`, and this seems to be what is used.

If you use `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'` you will get a better idea of the `PATH` being used. Note that I deliberately used `sh` instead of `bash` in order to bypass some of the initialisation files, which may change things, although `sh` will of course have some of its own.

On Ubuntu, the `secure_path` line does contain `/user/local/bin`, but CentOS may be different (both are derived from Debian, but according to `man sudoers` SELinux may override some entries). As far as I can see you have at least four options:-

- Modify `secure_path` to include `/usr/local/bin'.
- Put the link into one of the directories defined in `secure_path`.
- Use `su -c "{command} {parameters}"` instead of `sudo {command} {parameters}`.
- Use `sudo -s` to get a root `bash` with the same `PATH` initialisation as the original shell, then call your executable from there and exit afterwards.

I also found a lot of discussion and some other possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why).

Comment: There is no private messaging feature in StackExchange that I am aware of, so--I'll just post it here: having read through your user profile just now, I thought people like yourself probably don't get told often enough how much people like myself appreciate bumping into you in professional contexts. Hats off to you for your experience and support! If I were in the UK instead of LA, the first round would be on me. Salute! ( And thanks )